# Pass window object from an html anchor element

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a utility function which expects the window object to work on.

```
function someFunc(windowObj) { windowObj.someOtherFunc(); }
```

Now, I want to call this function `onclick` of a hyperlink, but the following code does not send the window object.

```
<a href='#' onclick='someFunc(this.window)'>Test</a>
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
<a href='#' onclick='someFunc(this)'>Test</a>
```

I understand in the latter case, `this` refers to the html anchor element itself.

Any thoughts how this can be done?

Comment: But... couldn't you just use `window`?

Comment: `window` is a global object. You can use it without passing it. try `function someFunc() { window.someOtherFunc(); }`

Comment: in onclick event this refers to a tag. DOM objects have no pointer to window as it is global object, available from anywhere in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window object is a global object which is referred to without the 'this' pointer.

Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunc(window)">Test</a>
```

instead and see if that works better.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to my comment.

`window` is a global object.Instead of passing the `window` object, you can do the following

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Test</a>
```

and the function can be

```
function someFunc() { window.someOtherFunc(); }
```

In short you do not need to pass the `window` object as it is accessible globally